# Is Homo sapiens the only extant species of genus "Homo"?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution

Is *Homo sapiens* the only species of genus "Homo" that survived?

Comment: Yes, it is, but there is evidence that older species have cross-bread, and, in some sense of the word, have survived. The concept of a genus is not well defined.

Comment: Some people argue that given our close relatedness Chimpanzees and humans should share a genus, which would likely be the genus Homo, meaning Homo sapiens would be one of three species in that genus. But it's not the official classification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Is *Homo sapiens* the only extant species of genus “*Homo*”?**

Yes, *Homo sapiens* is the only species left in the genus *Homo*. To be more accurate, some even consider all modern humans as being part of the same subspecies *Homo sapiens sapiens*. In those terms, *Homo sapiens sapiens* is the only subspecies left in the genus *Homo*.

There were other lineages before though but they got extinct.

**Other *Homo* lineages that existed**

There were other *Homo* lineages that went extinct. Consider the followings for example

- [*H. habilis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_habilis)
- [*H. gautengensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_gautengensis)
- [*H. erectus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_erectus)
- [*H. neanderthalensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal) (sometimes called *H. sapiens neanderthalensis*)
- [*H. heidelbergensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_heidelbergensis)

**Related posts**

Here are two other posts that may be of interest to you

- [Does it make sense to classify all humans in a single species?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57555/does-it-make-sense-to-classify-all-humans-in-a-single-species)
- [How could humans have interbred with Neanderthals if we're a different species?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39664/how-could-humans-have-interbred-with-neanderthals-if-were-a-different-species)